# Why will functions from the SystemModelConfiguration` package not evaluate?

Tags: documentation, version-11.3, compiler, system-modeling

**Documentation page now improved (checked in `v13.0`)**

According to the tutorial [Compiler for System Modeling](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CompilerForSystemModeling.html) I should be able to *verify the installation of a C++ compiler for the system modeling functionality* by:

```
SystemModelConfiguration`VerifyCompiler[]
```

Unfortunately it **will not evaluate in Mathematica 11.3.0** for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018).

Is this just a problem with my installation and if not, any ideas?

Comment: Since all functions listed in the tutorial will not evaluate it seems that the package is obsolete? This surprises me, as I had thought that everything connected with `SystemModel` is rather freshly integrated in Version 11.3.0 making the `WSMLink` package obsolete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just received a response from Wolfram Technical Support telling me that one has to load the `WSMLink` package for this functionality.

Indeed:

```
$Version
Needs["WSMLink`"];
SystemModelConfiguration`VerifyCompiler[]
```

> 11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)
>
> <|"Success" -> True|>

I have suggested an update to the documentation as the need to (still) load `WSMLink` does come as a surprise:  It is not mentioned anywhere on the main pages for system modeling functionality.

Comment: Alternatively, you can evaluate any symbol from the new system modeling functionality, and it should trigger the loading of the SystemModelConfiguration functions. So for example, you can evaluate `SystemModel`. I'll see to that this documentation page is improved.